# Role of Fermat's little theorem in the proof of correctness of ElGamal signature

Tags: elgamal-signature

In the Wikipedia article about the [ElGamal signature scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ElGamal_signature_scheme) it is written, that Fermat's little theorem is used in the following proof of correctness:

From the signature generation in ElGamal we can derive, that:

$$H(m) \equiv xr + sk \pmod {p-1}$$

Then - the article states - Fermat's little theorem implies the following:

$$\begin{align}
g^{H(m)} &\equiv g^{xr}g^{ks}   &\pmod p\\
         &\equiv (g^x)^r(g^k)^s &\pmod p\\
         &\equiv (y)^r(r)^s     &\pmod p
\end{align}$$

The proof makes sense to me, i am just wondering, in what way Fermat's little theorem is used here, instead of just [regular properties of exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Identities_and_properties).

Comment: Hint: apply the definition of $H(m)\equiv xr+sk\pmod{p-1}$ so that you remove the modulo. You should then see how establishing $g^{H(m)}\equiv g^{xr}g^{ks}\pmod p$ involves Fermat's little theorem.

Answer (score 3):

For $c\ne0$, the definition of $a\equiv b\pmod c$ is: $\exists d\in\mathbb Z$ such that $a=b+cd$.

Applying that definition to $H(m)\equiv xr+sk\pmod{p-1}$, we have that $\exists d\in\mathbb Z$ such that $H(m)=xr+sk+(p-1)d\;\text{ (equ. 1)}$.

Fermat's little theorem is that for $p$ prime and $g\not\equiv0\pmod p$, it holds that $g^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod p\;\text{ (equ. 2)}$.

We can now compute
$$\begin{align}
g^{H(m)} &\equiv g^{xr+sk+(p-1)d}&\pmod p&&\text{ (by equ. 1)}\\
         &\equiv {(g^x)}^r\;{(g^k)}^s\;(g^{p-1})^d&\pmod p&&\text{ (rearanging)}\\
         &\equiv {(g^x)}^r\;{(g^k)}^s\;1^d&\pmod p&&\text{ (by equ. 2)}\\
         &\equiv {(g^x)}^r\;{(g^k)}^s&\pmod p&&\text{ (simplifying)}\\
         &\equiv y^r\;r^s&\pmod p&&\text{ (by definition of }y\text{ and }r\text{)}
\end{align}$$

Comment: A living legend +1

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [fgrieu's comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/32152/role-of-fermats-little-theorem-in-the-proof-of-correctness-of-elgamal-signature/32154#comment74858_32152) above and the following quote from [here (PDF)](http://www.math.nyu.edu/faculty/hausner/fermat.pdf):

> **Theorem**:
>
> Let $p$ be a prime and let $a$ be a number not divisible by $p$. Then if
>   $$ r \equiv s \pmod {p − 1} $$
>   we have
>   $$ a^r \equiv a^s \pmod p$$ In brief, when we work $\mod p$, exponents can be taken $\mod{p − 1}$.

I (think i) understood, how the first (implicit) step relies on Fermat's little theorem:
$$\begin{align}
g^{H(m) \pmod{p-1}} &= g^{xr+sk \pmod{p-1}} \\
g^{H(m)} &\equiv g^{xr+sk} \pmod p
\end{align}$$